# Adding user input to a method and putting the results into a file (C++)

Tags: c++, eclipse, file, input, output

Any help would be appreciated. All I'm trying to do is ask for user input, do some calculations and print the results in a file. I thought that my code was correct but when I run my program, I get nothing. Here is my code. Not looking for an answer, just for any tips to lead me in the right direction. Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Employee{
private:
    int id;
    int job_class;
    int years_service;
    int Ed;
    float salary;
public:
    void getData(ifstream&);
    void computation(int job_class, int years_service, int Ed);
    void printout(ofstream&);
};

void Employee::getData(ifstream& infile){

infile >> id >> job_class >> years_service >> Ed;

}

void Employee::computation(int job_class, int years_service, int Ed){
int basePay = 800;
float jobresult, Yearresult, Edresult;

if(job_class == 1){
 jobresult = .05;
}

if(job_class == 2){
 jobresult = .10;
}

if(job_class == 3){
 jobresult = .15;
}

if(years_service <= 10){
 Yearresult =.05;
}

if(years_service > 10){
 Yearresult = .05;
}

if(Ed == 1){
 Edresult = .00;
}

if(Ed == 2){
 Edresult = .05;
}

if(Ed == 3){
 Edresult = .12;
}

if(Ed == 4){
 Edresult = .20;
}
salary = basePay + jobresult + Yearresult + Edresult;
//cout << salary;
}

void Employee::printout(ofstream& outfile){
outfile << "ID: " << "Salary " << endl;
outfile << id << salary;
}

int main(){

Employee emp; //created an Employee object
string input;


int id;
int job_class;
int years_service;
int Ed;
int basepay = 800;

cout << "Enter id" << endl;
cin >> id;
cout << "Enter job_class" << endl;
cin >> job_class;
cout << "Enter years of service" << endl;
cin >> years_service;
cout << "Enter education" << endl;
cin >> Ed;


 ifstream inFile;
 ofstream outFile;

//getline(cin, input);



 inFile.open("example.txt");
 outFile.open("examplee.txt");

//inFile.open(input);

std::string r = std::to_string(id); //converted id to string
inFile.open(r);
getline(cin, r);

std::string s = std::to_string(years_service);
inFile.open(s);
getline(cin, s);


std::string t = std::to_string(years_service);
inFile.open(t);
getline(cin, t);

 std::string u = std::to_string(Ed);
 inFile.open(u);
getline(cin, u);

if(inFile.is_open()){

emp.getData(inFile);
inFile.close();
}

outFile.open(r);

if(outFile.is_open()){

emp.computation(job_class, years_service, Ed);
float sal = basepay + job_class + years_service + Ed;

outFile << "ID " << "Salary " << endl;
outFile << id << sal;

outFile.close();
return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: You open and reopen the input file stream multiple times with different file names, and not one of those times do you read from the file.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to do with things like this?

```
std::string r = std::to_string(id); //converted id to string
inFile.open(r);   /*Opens a file whose name is <id> ???*/
getline(cin, r);  /*Overwrites the contents of r and does nothing??? */
```

Your entire program is fairly confusing. My best guess as to the (main) problem is that you aren't writing anything to `inFile` at all. Those 12 lines after `outFile.open("examplee.txt")` seem like they are trying to accomplish the following:

```
inFile << id << ' ' << job_class << ' ' << years_service << ' ' << ED << '\n';
```

Also, although I'm guessing this is for debugging purposes, but many of your methods do nothing or are unused. For example, you use `emp.computation(job_class, years, ED)` but after that you don't use `emp` at all in any way. And the three lines after that seem to mimic the behavior of `Employee::computation` and `Employee::printout`.

I suggest you carefully consider the specific steps you're trying to take, then think about the purpose of methods like `getline` and `fstream::open`, and ask yourself "Does this accomplish the task I had in mind?". Because I'm really struggling to understand what you are trying to do when I read this code.